# Laravel react userContext build issue

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vite

I have created a context component in context folder with this code

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // Or initial state

    // Any additional functions to manipulate user state

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
        );
};

enter code here

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

and this is the error I am getting on build

```
npm run build

> build
> vite build

vite v4.4.9 building for production...
✓ 3 modules transformed.
✓ built in 396ms
[vite:build-import-analysis] Parse error @:13:32
file: /var/www/clients/client2/web565/web/resources/js/context/UserContext.js:13:31
11:         <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
12:             {children}
13:         </UserContext.Provider>
                                   ^
14:         );
15: };
error during build:
Error: Parse error @:13:32
    at parse$e (file:///var/www/clients/client2/web565/web/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:16472:355)
    at Object.transform (file:///var/www/clients/client2/web565/web/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:46579:27)
web565@server2:/var/www/clients/client2/web565/web$
```